# regex except string

Tags: regex

Now are hours that I try to create a regex but without result.
I need a regex that returns true if it corresponds to this rule:   https?://example.it.* but returns false  ONLY IF corresponds to this specific URL https://example.it/hello

Is possible???

Thank you

Comment: because you're matching `.com` and the ccTLD is `.it`

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: remove the spaces, and you said .com instead of ".it/"

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `https?:\/\/example[.]it\/(?!hello).*`

Working example: http://regexr.com/3dc97

I'm guessing the follow up question would be if you can make domain dynamic but I'm sure you can figure that out.